# Bootstrap calendar show two calendar in IE 11

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, datetime, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Bootstrap calendar show two calendars in IE 11 when I click on << or >> icons to get previous or last month. Below is the code written to show calendar. Pls help. Thanks in advance.

```
$(".datepicker, .date").datepicker({
        format: 'dd M yyyy',
        weekStart: 1,
        todayBtn: "linked",
        showTodayButton: true,
        forceParse: false,
        //clearBtn: true,
        beforeShowDay: function (date) {
            var d = date.getDate();
            var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
            var y = date.getFullYear();

            if (holidayJson[y] && holidayJson[y][m] && holidayJson[y][m][d]) {
                var s = holidayJson[y][m][d];
                return {
                    tooltip: s.tooltip,
                    classes: s.className
                };
            } else {
                return { tooltip: '&nbsp;', classes: '' };
            }
        }
    });
```

I think problem is with beforeShowDay function if I remove it its working fine. Below is html code from html file and aspx file.

```
 <div class="input-append date" style="cursor: pointer; display: inline;">
    <input type="text" id="FromDate" class="form-control input-sm" onfocus="blur();" data-ng-model="ttsViewModel.FromDate" style="display: inline-block;" />
    <span class="add-on" id="FromDateAddOn" style="font-size: 16px; color: #c09853;"><i class="fa fa-calendar" style="padding-left: 3px; padding-top: 4px;"></i></span>
</div>

<div class="input-append date" style="cursor: pointer; display: inline;"  data-date-format="dd M yyyy">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFdate" Width="80px" runat="server" ToolTip="mm/dd/yyyy" ClientIDMode="Static" CssClass="form-control input-sm"   
            style="width: 80px; display: inline-block;" ></asp:TextBox>

    <span class="add-on" style="font-size: 16px; color: #c09853;"><i class="fa fa-calendar" style="padding-left: 3px; padding-top: 4px;"></i></span>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: Please include your HTML

Comment: yes..please insert html..

Comment: updated the html code snippet

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am running into the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by the way you are applying the datepicker functionality to your element/textbox. The class .datepicker is already used by the library itself for the datepicker window, using the same class name to indicate whigh elements to apply datepickers, cause your code to try to add a new datepicker on the datepicker popup itself (because it try to add a datepicker to every element having the class .datepicker, and the datepicker popup is using that class).

As far as I know, this seems to cause a bug only in the month switch and when using IE11, for whatever reasons. Maybe because other click in the datepicker popup cause a change of datepicker mode and a redraw of the datepicker.

Try simply using a different class than '.datepicker' to implement datepickers to your control (i.e.  .attachadatepickertothiscontrol)